# Memory inconsistency issue when doing DMA from memory to a device in user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, arm

I've spent quite a few hours trying to find out the root cause of an inconsistent memory behaviour in a user space driver. I seem to have managed to at least get it working, however, I still don't understand the root cause itself, and I'm not completely happy with the solution because it bypasses the kernel's memory management system.

First of all, a bit of background about this setup:

The platform is ARM based, and I'm running Linux (4.4)
I'm working on a user space driver (UIO) to control a very simple piece of hardware. This device needs to read from main memory (DMA), do some calculations on the data, and output the result in one of the registers.
The device is coherent with the ARM, because it's connected to the ACP port (this effectively means I don't need to flush caches or allocate DMA coherent memory).
Accessing the registers and the interrupt is very easy since the device is compatible with the uio-generic driver. The tricky part is allocating physically contiguous memory from user space and making sure that the device actually reads from where it should, at the right moment.

Now, I have tried two different ways of allocating this memory, one of which seems to be working, whilst the other is not.

The non-working solution consists basically of a very simple kernel module that mmaps physically contiguous memory in kernel space to a vm area in user space.

```
struct page *page = alloc_page(GFP_KERNEL);
vma->vm_pgoff = page_to_phys(page) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
SetPageReserved(page);
remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff, 1 << PAGE_SHIFT, vma->vm_page_prot))
```

What I observe in this case is that when the device reads from "memory" (quoted because it may actually read from L1/L2 cache as well), it gets stale data. I've also observed that if I wait after setting up the memory contents and before kicking off the device (e.g. by doing sleep(10)), this option works as well (obviously this is not acceptable, but at least it shows I'm writing at the right locations).

As for the working solution - I've reserved 2MB of memory by modifying the bootparams variable in uboot, so that the kernel doesn't even know it's there. Then, on the user space application side, I mmap /dev/mem at the appropriate address. This works always, which shows that, not only do I seem to be writing to the right locations, but also the device is read-coherent with the CPU.

I would really prefer the kernel-based solution. Does anyone know what might be going wrong here? I'm guessing the kernel is setting up the page table in a way that prevents the coherency port from working properly, but I don't know what to look at next. Does anyone know what the underlying differences are between these two approaches and what might be going wrong?

Comment: Is the device actually issuing transactions with the appropriate cacheability/shareability at the AXI level? (In other words, just because a device _can_ snoop the cache doesn't mean it necessarily _will_) I think /dev/mem should be giving you a non-cacheable mapping by default for things outside kernel RAM, so it's less of a surprise that the device can see writes when they're going straight through to memory without dirtying the cache.

Comment: The device itself is issuing cached transactions (judging by the AxCACHE AXI signals - unless there's something else I'm missing). However, if /dev/mem is giving me non-cacheable mappings, then that doesn't really matter I suppose, since those transactions will eventually reach the memory  controller anyway. Wondering whether there is a way to confirm that - I had a look at the /dev/mem code, but it wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: I have done a small micro benchmark that mmaps /dev/mem (just like before), copies 2MB of data to the memory, and then, in a loop, calculates the sum of all of the bytes. I have measured the number of L1 misses and L1 hits using the ARM PMU, and it looks like most of the time it hits the cache. Looks like memory it's actually cached and the ACP port is working properly when mapping /dev/mem

Comment: Did you find what was causing the kernel version not work properly?

Comment: I did not, I ended up doing it via /dev/mem I'm afraid.